# VBA Copy Paste Data into Excel from Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I'm running the code below and getting spurious results.

For some reason it copies five lines of code into the desired worksheet instead of the specified MS Project data.

Can Anyone help out a newbie?

Five lines of code incorrectly copied into Excel worksheet:

```
'Open MS Project file
projApp.Application.FileOpenEx "C:File.mpp"

Set projApp = projApp.ActiveProject

'Final set up of code
Set projApp = Nothing
```

[image: Error Image]

```
Sub OpenProjectCopyPasteData()

Dim appProj As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg As MSProject.Project
Dim sel As MSProject.Selection
Dim ts As Tasks
Dim t As Task
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Clear current contents

Set ws = Worksheets("Project Data")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:J")
rng.ClearContents

On Error Resume Next
Set appProj = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
If appProj Is Nothing Then
    Set appProj = New MSProject.Application
End If
appProj.Visible = True

'Open MS Project file
projApp.Application.FileOpenEx "C:File.mpp"
Set projApp = projApp.ActiveProject

'Final set up of code
Set projApp = Nothing

appProj.Visible = True

WindowActivate WindowName:=aProg

'Copy the project columns and paste into Excel
Set ts = aProg.Tasks

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Task Name"
OutlineShowAllTasks
OutlineShowAllTasks
EditCopy
Set ws = Worksheets("Project Data")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Task Name"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Resource Names"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("C:C")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Finish"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("D:D")
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=rng

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
appProj.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not also assign `ActiveSheet` to a variable too? It would help cut down on any ambiguity insofar as what is the ActiveSheet.

Comment: See my answer and code below

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you very much. Huge help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how your original code above worked, since you `Dim` and `Set` the variable `appProj`, but later trying to open the MS-Project file with `projApp.Application.FileOpenEx "C:File.mpp"` (`projApp` <> `appProj`).

Try the code below (tested), it will copy the 3 columns (`"Name"` , `"Resource Names"` and `"Finish"`) to worksheet "Project Data" at columns "A:C".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenProjectCopyPasteData()

Dim PrjApp      As MSProject.Application
Dim aProg       As MSProject.Project
Dim PrjFullName As String
Dim t           As Task
Dim rng         As Range
Dim ws          As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Clear current contents
Set ws = Worksheets("Project Data")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:J")
rng.ClearContents

On Error Resume Next
Set PrjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
If PrjApp Is Nothing Then
    Set PrjApp = New MSProject.Application
End If
On Error GoTo 0
PrjApp.ScreenUpdating = False
PrjApp.Visible = True

'Open MS Project file
PrjFullName = "C:File.mpp" '<-- keep the MS-Project file name and path in a variable
PrjApp.Application.FileOpenEx PrjFullName
Set aProg = PrjApp.ActiveProject

' show all tasks
OutlineShowAllTasks

'Copy the project columns and paste into Excel
SelectTaskColumn Column:="Name"
EditCopy
Set ws = Worksheets("Project Data")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Resource Names"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B")
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

SelectTaskColumn Column:="Finish"
EditCopy
Set rng = ws.Range("C:C")
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

' reset settings of Excel and MS-Project
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
PrjApp.ScreenUpdating = True
PrjApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'PrjApp.FileClose False
PrjApp.Quit pjDoNotSave
Set PrjApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble modifying this to loop through paths stored in a worksheet (instead of having the paths defined in the code). Any suggestions there? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012400/misunderstood-runtime-error-vba-for-excel-and-ms-project)

Comment: @ERKSMTY  you should post a new question, describe exactly what you are trying to achieve, and add your relevant code. This will allow other users and myself to help you

Comment: check out the link in my last comment